# Prevent hydration model objects with eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to understand what happen when using the toArray () method in a case like this:

```
Ad::query()->with('nominations')->where(['id'=>$id])->get()->toArray();
```

Eloquent prevents the construction of the collection and the hydration of individual model objects and directly returns an array or eloquent first hydrates the collection and the model objects and then converts everything into an array (thus doing an extra operation)?

If the answer was the second, how can I get the first behavior with eloquent?

I specify with eloquent because it would be nice to be able to do this by continuing to refer in an abstract way to the entities without then mentioning specific database features in the code (for example the name of the tables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering both your questions. The second one will happen. And you can't make Eloquent create an array, you can just convert an object or collection to an array.

Also, your query has a lot of redundant code, you could just do this:

```
Ad::with('nominations')->find($id)->toArray()
```